# Get State from City PHP

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3

```
   Is it possible to find state from city as like we can find city ,address or   
   state from zipcode or latitude longitude..??Is there any API available for  
   that. ?
```

Actually I want state name by entering city name.May be i am here wrong but just wanted to confirm.

Comment: It is possible via google map API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use the following API

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=mumbai&sensor=false

Open this in your browser and you will see the resultset

Comment: Thanks Bhawana.
i wanted this only.